# Transformar fundo de botões, textos em transparente - python - customtkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Quando faço esse código no PYTHON usando CUSTOMTKINTER, o bg color não funciona ao coloca lo transparente

def interacoes(self):
# Campo a inserir a data
self.entry = tk.CTkEntry(self, width=220, height=30, text_color=['#696969', 'white' ],
placeholder_text='Insira a data de nascimento',
bg_color="transparent", placeholder_text_color='#696969')
self.entry.pack(pady=20)
self.entry.place(relx=0.52, rely=0.25)

```
    # Botão para verificar a data
    self.button = tk.CTkButton(self, width=200, height=30, text='Verificar' ,font=('Bahnschrift', 15),
                               fg_color='green', command=self.verificar_data, hover_color='#006400')
    self.button.place(relx=0.533, rely=0.37)

    # Botão para limpar o campo e o resultado
    self.button_clear = tk.CTkButton(self, text="Limpar", font=('Bahnschrift', 14),
                                     command=self.clear).place(relx=0.8, rely=0.9)
```

Está tudo certo, só que o BG_color não funciona quando coloco transparente. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgILd.png)

Tentei colocar o fundo em transparente.[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifwGT.png)

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.